# Strange error in production with node.js and nginx: "Error: Request aborted"

Tags: node.js, unix, nginx, express

I really don't know what is happening but the request is aborted at some time and only happens in production on the unix machine. On my windows machine works everything fine.

I'm using express and express.bodyParser. There is many things that it depends, so ask me what I need to provide in order to help me.

Error:

```
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/var/apps/xxx/node_modules/easy-express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:131:17)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at abortIncoming (http.js:1912:11)
    at Socket.socket.onend (http.js:2004:7)
    at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Here I've seen this https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty:
'aborted'
Emitted when the request is aborted. This event will be followed shortly by an error event. In practice you do not need to handle this event.

What is strange is that it works. The only problem is the error in the log really. I think it might have other problems.

Thanks (:

Comment: Related to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973257/request-aborted-on-expressjs/46497311#46497311