# Request aborted on expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am using expressjs and multer to handle upload of files on my nodejs server.
I am often getting this error in production logs :

```
Error: Request aborted
at onaborted (/home/drp/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:951:15)
at Array.onfinish [as 0] (/home/drp/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:987:50)
at listener (/home/drp/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:164:15)
at onFinish (/home/drp/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:95:5)
at callback (/home/drp/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:33:10)
at Socket.onevent (/home/drp/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:66:5)
at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
at net.js:440:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

What does it really mean ?
How can I trace it and debug it ?

Comment: Did you look at the listed source code lines for clues as to what part of your code this is connected to?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `nginx` on top of this. Try restart it.

Or any load balancer, sometimes those sends across incorrect request 200 (or 304 or different requests) doing ExpressJS answering with this fail and producing the `Error: Request aborted`.